# Copy file permissions from user to group

Tags: permissions, files

I have a folder with some files, which each have different permissions. Some are read-only, some are read/write, some are read/execute.

How can I copy the permissions from user to group, so that for example a file marked read-write for user will be set to read-write for group, but a file read-executable for a user will be set read-executable for the group.

Can this be done with a single command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chmod` from coreutils understands such assignments:

```
chmod g=u file
```

Comment: just a joke :)

#! /bin/bash
for FILE in *
        do chmod g=$(ls -l $FILE | cut -c 2,3,4) $FILE
done